# Mongodb pipeline match with items of previous lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query doing a pipeline lookup and the result is stored as a new array under the key name "A", I could not find an example, of how to add another pipeline to inject another lookup under the key "B", but using a match with fields from the first lookup.
Something like
select all documents from collection ROOT,
Add documents from collection A where A.id=ROOT.id as array A, and add documents from collection B where A.x=B.x as arrays A.B

A collection example with desired output:

```
ROOT {"_id":1,"type":"customer","name":"anton"}
A {"_id":33, "customer":1, "type":"order","address":"azores island"}
B {"_id":"1_33_1", "type":"item","name":"golf ball"}

and want to achieve this output. the id incollection B is in the format of customerId_orderId_itemIndex, a string join

{"_id":1,"type":"customer","name":"anton",
"orders": [
    {
    "_id":33, "customer":1, "type":"order","address":"azores island", 
    "items":[{"_id":"33_1", "type":"item","name":"golf ball"}]
    }
]}
```

Comment: I think there are multiple ways to do this, but it's a little difficult to advise on the specifics without more specifics around what you want. Can you edit your question to provide some sample input documents from the three collections and the output you would expect from them? A mongoplayground link that has a copy of the data (and any pipeline that you've attempted) would be appreciated as well

Comment: thank you, I added an example for clarity. What I can do is the first lookup, to create orders in the result. but not items within those orders.

Answer (score 0):

> the id in collection `B` is in the format of `customerId_orderId_itemIndex`, a string join

This makes the effort of joining the data much more convoluted. Relatedly, it's not immediately obvious to me why you would want to store the information in collection `B` separate from the orders in `A`  as opposed to embedding them in an array. Personally I'd strongly recommend at least considering that as it could drastically simplify current and future development.

Nevertheless, you can achieve the goal stated in your question with something similar to the following:

```
db.ROOT.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "A",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "customer",
      "as": "orders",
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "B",
            let: {
              regex: {
                "$concat": [
                  "^",
                  {
                    $toString: "$customer"
                  },
                  "_",
                  {
                    "$toString": "$_id"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $regexMatch: {
                      input: "$_id",
                      regex: "$$regex"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "as": "items"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Here we:

1. Perform a (simple) `$lookup` between `ROOT` and `A` to get the relevant `orders` documents.
2. Nested inside of that operation we do another `$lookup` between `A` and `B` to get the relevant `items` documents.

   - Notably here we have to jump through some hoops to construct a regex pattern which we can use when matching against the `_id` field for documents in `B`.

Using the following sample data:

```
"ROOT": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "type": "customer",
      "name": "anton"
    }
  ],
  "A": [
    {
      "_id": 33,
      "customer": 1,
      "type": "order",
      "address": "azores island"
    }
  ],
  "B": [
    {
      "_id": "1_33_1",
      "type": "item",
      "name": "golf ball"
    },
    {
      "_id": "1_33_2",
      "type": "item",
      "name": "golf club"
    },
    {
      "_id": "2_33_1",
      "type": "item",
      "name": "golf ball"
    }
  ]
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "anton",
    "orders": [
      {
        "_id": 33,
        "address": "azores island",
        "customer": 1,
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": "1_33_2",
            "name": "golf club",
            "type": "item"
          },
          {
            "_id": "1_33_1",
            "name": "golf ball",
            "type": "item"
          }
        ],
        "type": "order"
      }
    ],
    "type": "customer"
  }
]
```

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uBVK9FcROUf)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, the data model is far from optimal, but it is not much my choice :( 
Will test this over the weekend.